# Can I set the value of a variable by using the address within DXL doors?

Tags: ibm-doors

So what I want to do is pass a variable into an `eval_` by address and then set the variable in there like so:

```
string str = "a"
Addr64_ addr = addr_ str
eval_("string ref = addr_ " addr "; ref = \"b\"")
print str // I want it to print b here
```

I realize I could `evalTop_` here to make the top variable available to the eval so it can set it, but this is not the behavior that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging and combining different answers from the following sources:

[Memory hacks 1](https://ibmsf.force.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006HIFoFCAX/doors-64-bit-memory-hacks-doors-9617-and-upwards?language=en_US)

[Memory hacks 2](https://ibmsf.force.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006HIFoFCAX/doors-64-bit-memory-hacks-doors-9617-and-upwards?language=en_US)

I found a solution! the following code should work for basically any variable:

```
bool a = false
eval_("bool &a = addr_ " (addr_ (&a)) "; a = true")

print a // should print true
```